# Trying to run elementary on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

Im trying to run the latest elementary image on virtualbox 5.2 from a host of mint 18.2 KDE but i just get a black screen with flashing terminal cursor.

Iv checked all the tutorials and im not short of any specs or doing anything wrong (that i can see) , iv got loads of virtual OS's on various virtualbox's so i reasonably comfortable with using it but i just cant get elementary to run its .iso at all?

[image]

Comment: just a suggestion ... i have run Loki in VirtualBox and have not had issues ... maybe the iso file is bad? Suggest you download the iso again to see it that solves the issue

Comment: ok i shall try the straight download instead of the torrent this time.

Comment: well bugger me backwards, it worked. Many thx

Comment: @GeorgeBarbaz perhaps add that as an answer, as a lack of answered questions is holding back this Stack Exchange from leaving Beta, plus you deserve rep for providing working solution. :-D

Comment: Maybe try another app like Gnome Boxes or Virt Manager

Comment: Why not install it in your machine which provides the best experience?

Answer (score 1):

okay ... as suggested by Sam Morrow Drums ... adding my comment/suggestion as a solution that apparently worked for this user

just a suggestion ... i have run Loki in VirtualBox and have not had issues ... maybe the iso file is bad? Suggest you download the iso again to see it that solves the issue

Jack Dinn (opener of this question) replied that this worked.